# MySql Query for Max(Date) not Today

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table:

Name -   Date
Adam - 7-13-19
Stan - 7-13-19
Adam-  7-11-19
Bob -  7-10-19
Stan-  7-10-19
Eric-  7-10-19
Lucy-  7-09-19
Eric-  7-09-19
Bob -  7-09-19
Lucy -  7-08-19

I would like to pull each unique name (which I'm using GROUP BY to do) and the latest corresponding date for each name (which I'm using Max(date) to do).  However, I don't want the name to appear if the max(date) is equal to today's date (7-13-19).  So the end result I'm looking for is:

Bob
Eric
Lucy

The list would not include Adam or Stan...since they both have max dates of 7-13-19.  I've tried a whole bunch of queries, but can't get it to work.  My initial thought was something like this:

```
SELECT *, max(date)
FROM table
WHERE max(date) <> date(now())
GROUP BY name
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use aggregate results as a filter, you need to use the HAVING clause.

Something like this should work for you.

```
SELECT name
    , MAX(date) AS max_date
FROM table 
GROUP BY name
HAVING MAX(date(date)) <> DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: It's grouping them together; however, it still pulling all of the max(date)s and not excluding the ones that match the date(now()).  any thoughts?

Comment: To clarify the source table the data is dates and not date times?  (Even a midnight value is not equal to date(now()))

Comment: it's a timestamp that includes the dates and time.  does that matter?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: I think that did the trick! :-)  Thanks!